# Adapter RecyclerView не видит root

Tags: android, kotlin, recyclerview, root, viewholder

Я изменил макет item xml файла с `androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout` на `layout`, после чего `root` в `FoodItemViewHolder` стал выделяться красным:

```
class FoodItemAdapter(private val context: Context, private val names: List<String>, private val text: List<String>)
    : RecyclerView.Adapter<FoodItemAdapter.FoodItemViewHolder>() {


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): FoodItemViewHolder {
        val binding = FoodItemLayoutBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context),parent,false)
        return FoodItemViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: FoodItemViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val foodItem = names[position]
        val foodItem2 = text[position]
        holder.bind(foodItem, foodItem2)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return names.size
    }


    class FoodItemViewHolder(val foodItemLayoutBinding: FoodItemLayoutBinding)
        : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(foodItemLayoutBinding.root){

        private val binding = foodItemLayoutBinding

        fun bind(foodItem: String, foodItem2: String){
            binding.foodItemNameTV.text = foodItem
            binding.foodItemPriceTV.text = foodItem2
        }

    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На `layout` вы заменили имея в виду использование DataBinding? Коли да, и оно не работает, то можно попробовать Чистку проекта сделаь и/или даже InvalidateCacheAndRestart студии

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, к сожалению, не помогло

Comment: А dataBibdibg у вас вообще работает? Или вы только начали его встраивать? Может он в build. cradle не подключён?

Comment: Разметку покажите. И зачем поменяли?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, я и правда не добавил DataBinding, огромное Вам спасибо!

Comment: @ArtyMorris, решил закрепить изученый материал на практике

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы DataBinding заработал - надо его [явно включить](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/start#build_environment) в `build.gradle(module app)`

```
android {
    ...
    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding true
    }
}
```

---

Вообще завязываться на гугловые либы, использующие кодогенерацию по XML - плохая идея в том смысле, что часто что-то ломается так, что не выдаёт каких-то понятных ошибок. Как в этом случае, так и в случае либы для навигации (там это пытаются исправить через либу SafeArgs). Даже `ViewBinding` иногда ломается страшным образом (у меня, например, полпроекта сломалось из-за пустого коммента в разметке так, что студия не подключала стороннюю либу странным образом. Ошибку нашёл методом везения).

ИМХО - лучше не использовать либы от гугла с кодогенерацией по XML.